# How to change parameters of a Logic App using powershell command Set-AzureRmLogicApp?

Tags: azure-powershell, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to change a parameter in my Logic App after deployment using powershell. I have tried the following command which runs successfully but does not update the Logic App.

```
@hashTable = @{"parameterName" = "value which i want to be placed"}

Set-AzureRmLogicApp -ResourceGroupName RGName -Name LAName -Parameters $hashTable -Force
```

I am using powershell because of limited run permission on the target location.

Comment: The documentation of [Set-AzureRmLogicApp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.logicapp/set-azurermlogicapp) is pretty frustrating. It does not gives the structure in which parameters needs to be passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of the parameters can be checked with this command:

```
(Get-AzureRmLogicApp -ResourceGroupName resGroup -Name logicAppName).Parameters

Key        Value
---        -----
param1 Microsoft.Azure.Management.Logic.Models.WorkflowParameter
```

I found that the easiest way to update one parameter is this get-update-set chain:

```
$lapp = Get-AzureRmLogicApp -ResourceGroupName resGroup -Name logicAppName
$lapp.Parameters['param1'].Value = "NEW_VALUE"
Set-AzureRmLogicApp -ResourceGroupName resGroup -Name logicAppName -Parameters $lapp.Parameters
```

So the key point is to update the Value property of the parameter in your command. Played with this last week and wrote a blog post on the subject: https://www.bilot.fi/updating-azure-logic-app-parameters-with-powershell/